# Spring boot cache evict not working from another thread

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-boot, caching

I can't understand why `cache evict` is not working in my scenario. I have an application that has a scheduled service in it and has MVC for user to click some stuff.

```
@Cacheable(value = "applicationToken")
public Optional<String> getToken() {
    return settingsRepository.getToken();
}

@CacheEvict(value = "applicationToken", allEntries = true)
public void evictApplicationTokenCache() {
    log.info("Evicting token cache.");
}

public void updateToken(String token) {
    log.info("Updating token.");

    settingsRepository.updateToken(token);
    evictApplicationTokenCache();
}
```

The method `getToken()` is called inside the scheduled service and when I tried some test to evict cache from there it worked.
However, on the MVC side, if the user updates the token, the method `updateToken()` gets called and although it goes inside the `evictApplicationTokenCache()`, on the next retrieval of the token, I still get the same token and it doesn't step into the method `getToken()` to actually grab the token from the repository.

The only relation I found is that the threads are different for the MVN call and for the Scheduled call. From what I know, the cache should live on the context level, not the thread level. Therefore, it shouldn't matter which thread asks for the cache to be evicted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `updateToken()` and `evictApplicationTokenCache()` methods are in the same class.

In that case, the `@CacheEvict` annotation will be ignored, because cache handling is implemented by interceptors that are only involved when you call a method from one component to a different (injected) component.

If that's the situation, you can move the `evictApplicationTokenCache()` method to a helper `@Component`, or put the `@CacheEvict` annotation on the `updateToken()` method.

Comment: I will give it a try. Thanks, most likely this will solve the issue. I totally forgot about this

Comment: @Santiago Medina - Thanks a lot for this answer. I too have cache evict call in the same class.. I'm banging my head since 2hrs why cacheevict not working when called within class..

Answer (score 0):

methods annotated with @Cacheable or @CacheEvict will be executed using AOP. and as the aspect is applied to a proxy surrounding the bean, the direct call to the bean will not fire evict cache...
So make sure :

1 - you are calling the method annotated with @EvictCache from another Spring context bean.

2 - or use the cache manger bean

```
...

@Autowired
CacheManager cacheManager;

...
    
Optional.ofNullable(cacheManager.getCache("THE_CACHE_NAME"))
.ifPresent(
    cache -> cache.evictIfPresent("THE_KEY"));
```